# Aligning node to be both to the right and above

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

The screenshot below shows that I almost have what I want:
[image]

It's just that block 2 is hidden by block 3. I'd like block 2 to be higher by 1 cm and block 3 to be lower by 1 cm.

Here is my code, how do I do that:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% Define custom colors based on metropolis theme
\definecolor{blockoutline}{RGB}{79,106,133} % Color for block outline
\definecolor{blockbg}{RGB}{245,245,245} % Color for block background


\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Introduction}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      block/.style={
        draw=blockoutline, % Use custom block outline color
        fill=blockbg, % Use custom block background color
        line width=1.1pt,
        minimum width=2cm,
        minimum height=1.5cm, 
        rounded corners=8pt
      },
      arrow/.style={
        ->,
        >=latex,
        thick,
        shorten >=2pt,
        blockoutline % Use custom block outline color for arrows
      }
    ]
      % Define the blocks
      \node [block] (block1) {Block 1};
      \node [block, right=1cm of block1] (block2) {Block 2};
      \node [block, right=1cm of block1] (block3) {Block 3};
      \node [block, right=1cm of block3] (block4) {Block 4};

      % Connect the blocks
      \draw [arrow] (block1) -- (block2);
      \draw [arrow] (block1) -- (block3);
      \draw [arrow] (block2) -- (block4);
      \draw [arrow] (block3) -- (block4);

      % Figure title
      \node[below, font=\Large\bfseries] at (block1.south) {Block Diagram};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}

\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda hacky, but I got it.

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Introduction}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      block/.style={
        draw=blockoutline, % Use custom block outline color
        fill=blockbg, % Use custom block background color
        line width=1.1pt,
        minimum width=2cm,
        minimum height=1.5cm, 
        rounded corners=8pt
      },
      arrow/.style={
        ->,
        >=latex,
        thick,
        shorten >=2pt,
        blockoutline % Use custom block outline color for arrows
      }
    ]
      % Define the blocks
      \node [block] (block1) {Block 1};
      \node [block, above right = 0.3cm and 2cm of block1] (block2) {Block 2};
      \node [block, below right = 0.3cm and 2cm of block1] (block3) {Block 3};
      \node [block, right=6cm of block1] (block4) {Block 4};

      % Connect the blocks
      \draw [arrow] (block1) -- ++(2cm,0) |- (block2);
      \draw [arrow] (block1) -- ++(2cm,0) |- (block3);
      \draw [blockoutline, line width=0.75pt] (block2.east) -- ++(1cm,0) coordinate (b2) |- (block3.east);
      \draw [blockoutline, line width=0.75pt] (block3.east) -- ++(1cm,0) coordinate (b3) |- (block2.east);
      \draw [arrow] ($(b2)!0.5!(b3)$) -- ++(0.5cm,0) |- (block4.west);

      % Figure title
      \node[below, font=\Large\bfseries] at (block3.south) {Block Diagram};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}

\end{frame}
```